# Loop through groups of records in Oracle SQL procedure

Tags: xml, oracle, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure which generates a row of XML data derived from the entire contents of a table in Oracle SQL:

```
PROCEDURE TABLE_TO_XML(
TABLE_IN IN VARCHAR2,
XML_TABLE IN VARCHAR2,
ROW_ID IN INTEGER,
ENCODING IN VARCHAR2,
HEADER_TAG IN VARCHAR2,
ROWS_TAG IN VARCHAR2,
ROW_TAG IN VARCHAR2,
XMLHEADING IN VARCHAR2,
XMLFULLHEADING IN VARCHAR2
)
IS
    ctx DBMS_XMLQUERY.ctxHandle;
    xml CLOB;
BEGIN

    ctx := DBMS_XMLQUERY.NEWCONTEXT('SELECT * FROM '||TABLE_IN);

    DBMS_XMLQUERY.SETENCODINGTAG(ctx , ENCODING);  
    DBMS_XMLQUERY.SETDATAHEADER(ctx, 'deletethisblankline', HEADER_TAG);
    DBMS_XMLQUERY.SETROWSETTAG(ctx, ROWS_TAG);
    DBMS_XMLQUERY.SETROWTAG(ctx, ROW_TAG);
    DBMS_XMLQUERY.SETROWIDATTRNAME(ctx,null);
    DBMS_XMLQUERY.USENULLATTRIBUTEINDICATOR(ctx,FALSE);

    xml := DBMS_XMLQUERY.GETXML(ctx);
    xml := REPLACE(xml,'deletethisblankline'||CHR(10),'');
    xml := REPLACE(xml,'<'||XMLHEADING||'>','<'||XMLFULLHEADING||'>');

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO '||XML_TABLE||' VALUES(:x,:y)' USING ROW_ID, SYS.XMLTYPE.CREATEXML(xml);
    COMMIT;
    DBMS_XMLQUERY.CLOSECONTEXT(ctx);

END TABLE_TO_XML;
```

The source table of this data is enormous, so I end up with an XML file so large that it fails to import to its intended destination. Is there a straight forward way I can split the results by a particular number of rows, and for each group of records generate a full XML file (including all headers and footers specificed), without changing how the procedure is called?

Most functions in Oracle seem to have the ability to natively split things up, but I haven't found anything like that for the XML functions.